Was Remmina recently added to startup items in some recent (2024-04-25) update on 23.10
I restarted and noticed a strange applet icon in the top right. It was remmina. I didn't remember ever installing this so started looking into it. Apparently it's installed by default and is the RDP client.
I don't remember seeing this icon before and don't really use RDP. I think it should not be on (started) by default as this is a security issue (less attack surface better).
Anyone know what is going on?
I check my notes and I don't think I enabled this myself but hard to know for sure.

Does this answer your question? Uninstall preinstalled apps in Ubuntu 23.10
